# enterprise architect database abstraction

Tags: sql-server, enterprise-architect

Is there a data layer abstration avaliable for enterprise architect that doesn't reley on the add-in model?

I'm trying to intergrate EA into a build system, but would like to avoid going directly to the backing database.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do during the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: EA's Object Model.

The Object Model is not dependent on the Add-In Model (but the reverse applies). The Object Model API is available in Java and .NET, and gives full access to the models and most other information in an EA repository.

In other words, you can write a stand-alone application which accesses an EA repository from outside EA (ie not an Add-In) using these API:s rather than SQL.

Indeed, the repository database schema is not publicly documented, is not guaranteed not to change between EA versions, and is not intended to be used for adaptation development. You can do it but it is, as you've noted, a bad idea.